# Clarification about existence of limit random variable (for convergence in distribution).

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(X_n)_n$ a sequence of random variables on this space. Let $\mu: \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,1]$ a probability distribution

Suppose that $\mathbb{P}_{X_n} \stackrel{w}\to \mu $. Does there exist a random variable $Y$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ with $\mu = \mathbb{P}_Y?$

I looked here:

[Weak convergence of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519999/weak-convergence-of-random-variables?rq=1)

The answer in this question seems to indicate that the answer is true. However, one of the comments says that this is false.

What is the right answer?

I can't find a mistake in either of them.

Is it maybe that the random variables in the answer itself are allowed to take the values $\pm \infty$? Does this make the difference?

Comment: I think not. Suppose $\Omega$ is countable and the $X_n$ are discrete random variables that converge weakly to a continuous random variable. Clearly we cannot have a continuous random variable defined on a countable sample space. So we need to have some conditions on $\Omega$ for this to be possible.

Comment: Does this mean then that the answer provided in that answer is wrong?

Comment: Actually, maybe not. For it may be the case that in order for a sequence of distributions to converge weakly to a continuous distribution that $\Omega$ must be uncountable. I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Will Nelson in the thread you linked looks fine to me. The argument where „$\Omega$ is countable and $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of random variables such that their pushforward measures converge weakly to a continuous measure“ is flawed. The reason is that in this case there must be an $\mathcal F$-atom $A$ of positive $\mathbb P$-measure and then when $x_n$ is the value of $X_n$ on $A$, there must be a limit point $y\in[-\infty, +\infty]$ of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. It is then not difficult to check that $\mu(\{y\})\geq\mathbb P(A)>0$ and thus $\mu$ cannot be continuous.

Edit: With an $\mathcal F$-atom I meant an atom of $\mathcal F$ understood as a boolean algebra. In this case this means some $A\neq\emptyset$ in $\mathcal F$ so that if $B\subsetneq A$ and $B\in\mathcal F$ then $B=\emptyset$. Such an atom $A$ with positive $\mu$-measure most exist, which can be seen as follows: Since $\Omega$ is countable  and $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, for every $\omega\in\Omega$ there is a unique $\mathcal F$-atom $A_\omega$ with $\omega\in\Omega$. This can be seen by an application of Zorn's lemma for example. Consider $Z=\{B\in\mathcal F\mid \omega\in B\}$ ordered by $\supseteq$. As $\Omega$ is countable, any chain in $(Z, \supseteq)$ is countable and as $\mathcal F$ is closed under countable intersections, every chain there has an upper bound (namely the intersection over all elements of the chain). Thus there is a maximal element in $Z$, it is now easy to see that this is what we were looking for. 
Now finally, $\Omega=\bigcup_{\omega\in\Omega} A_\omega$ and as $\Omega$ is countable, we may use countable additivity of $\mu$ to see that 
$$1=\mu(\Omega)\leq\Sigma_{\omega\in\Omega}\mu(A_\omega)$$
hence there must be some $\omega$ so that $A_\omega$ has positive measure.

Comment: What exactly is an atom?

Comment: With an atom I meant an element of $\mathcal F$ whose only proper subset that is measured as well is the empty set.

Comment: Can you please add some detaiils why this should exist?

Comment: Quick reminder! Bounty expires tomorrow! 150rep can be yours if you add some details...

Comment: @user661541 what's your question? can you phrase it as an independent question for me, please? I think your question is of the form "why must there be an atom under [insert circumstances]"..

Comment: @mathworker21 Why is there an $\mathcal{F}$-atom $A$ of positive $\mathbb{P}$-measure in this case? And how does this imply that there is $y$ s.t. $\mu\{y\}> 0$?

Comment: @user661541 please state it as a completely independent question. i don't know what "in this case" means, which was the whole point of my first comment to you.

Comment: As you I'm just asking clarification. I'm not sure what the answerer meant with this sentence so I cannot be sure.

Comment: I was too late to award the bounty, but fair is fair you will get another one once I get more reputation. Thanks again and I'll definitelt come back!